# example of a flat but not faithfully flat ring extension

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory, modules

I am learning commutative algebra and there is a definition about faithfully flat modules or ring extensions. I can't think of an example of a flat but not faithfully flat ring extension or module. Can someone help me with it? thanks

Comment: Localization homomorphism $R\to S^{-1}R$ is flat but, in general, not faithfully flat.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take $f: A \rightarrow B$ to be a ring homomorphism such that the corresponding morphism of affine schemes $\operatorname{Spec}B \rightarrow \operatorname{Spec}A$ is not surjective, but only flat. There is an easy way to do this: Remember that localizing a ring $R$ in a multiplicative subset $S$ gives a flat ring homomorphism $R \rightarrow S^{-1}R$. However, this ring homomorphism is faithfully flat iff $S^{-1}R=R$.

Comment: I was about to give this answer!  It makes me wonder why commutative algebra is taught in isolation from algebraic geometry, since the intuition of "a local isomorphism should be flat" and "a surjective flat map is faithfully flat" makes it trivial to come up with an example.

Comment: @RyanReich : I agree. I believe there is little value of teaching students commutative algebra without teaching them some algebraic geometry along the way. Constructions such as these (or similar ones) becomes trivial.

Answer (score 12):

$0$ is always flat, but not faithfully flat (unless the base is $0$).

Answer (score 11):

A possibly instructive, concrete example is $\Bbb{Q}$ as an abelian group (i.e. as a $\Bbb{Z}$-module). Of course, this is just a special case of Dedalus's answer (and YACP's comment), but let's still prove the result directly.

Clearly $\Bbb{Q}$ is not a faithfully flat abelian group, e.g. the zero morphism
$$
\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z} \rightarrow 0
$$
is not injective, but after tensoring with $\Bbb{Q}$ this morphism is the identity on the zero  group (as $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z} \otimes \Bbb{Q} \cong 0$).

On the other hand, $\Bbb{Q}$ is a flat abelian group. To see this, assume that
$$
f: A \hookrightarrow B
$$
is an injective morphism of abelian groups, and consider the induced morphism
$$
f \otimes id: A \otimes \Bbb{Q} \rightarrow B \otimes \Bbb{Q}
$$
Now for $b \in B$ the element $b \otimes 1 \in B \otimes \Bbb{Q}$ is equal to zero, if and only if $b$ is torsion. So the kernel of $f \otimes id$ consists precisely of the elements $f(a) \otimes id$, such that $f(a)$ is torsion. But injectivity of $f$ implies that $a$ must be torsion as well, i.e. $a \otimes 1=0$. This shows that $f \otimes id$ is injective, and therefore $\Bbb{Q}$ is a flat abelian group.

Comment: Alternatively a module over a PID is flat iff torsion free.